# How big is a class in memory?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

How do I figure out how many bytes a `defclass` object has in Common Lisp?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that in portable Common Lisp.

Useful could be the function [`ROOM`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_room.htm). `ROOM` prints memory statistics and with the argument `T` it prints them detailed. So you may see a difference before and after some instance creations. Implementations may have specific functions, but you need to check that with the manual or with the support mailing list.

Comment: Interesting. (side explanation: I am dealing with lots of things and I'm trying to figure out how to optimize them smaller)

Comment: Some implementations will let you profile allocation to find the hotspots. That's much a much better way to improve the footprint.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Rainer's answer, here is the answer for CLISP: macro [`EXT:TIMES`](http://clisp.org/impnotes/debugger.html#time)

```
(defclass c () ((x) (y) (z)))
(ext:times (make-instance 'c))
                                   Permanent            Temporary
Class                         instances   bytes    instances   bytes
-----                         --------- ---------  --------- ---------
C                                     1        48          0         0
-----                         --------- ---------  --------- ---------
Total                                 1        48          0         0
Real time: 1.4E-5 sec.
Run time: 0.0 sec.
Space: 48 Bytes
#<C #x000333CF2AA0>
```

NB: if you evaluate `defclass` at the prompt, it is not compiled, so `times` will report some fluff in addition to `c`.